# Kernel of formal differentiation in a field of characteristic $0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

From the previous parts I've proven that

$$D:F[x]\to F[x]$$

is an additive group homomorphism on addition for $F[x]$ and **not** a ring homomorphism because the multiplication does not hold.

OK, so I do not understand why the kernel of $D$ is $F$. Can someone please explain that intuitively to me? Also is the image $D(F[x])$, $F[x]$ because its mapping into itself?  If you can clarify my reasoning for this that would be great.

Comment: Yes, it is a group homomorphism instead of a ring homomorphism. After you understand that, the rest is analysis problem: when is the derivative of a polynomial 0? which polynomial can be the derivative of another polynomial?

Answer (score 4):

Formal differentiation takes a polynomial

$p(x)=a_Nx^N+\ldots +a_1x+a_0$ and produces

$$Dp(x)= Na_Nx^{N-1}+(N-1)a_{N-1}x^{N-2}+\ldots + a_2x+a_1$$

Then in order for this to be the zero polynomial--since the field has characteristic $0$--it must be that $a_N, a_{N-1},\ldots, a_1=0$, otherwise the largest $k$ such that $a_k\ne 0$ gives a non-zero leading term $ka_kx^{k-1}$ for $Dp(x)$. This implies that kernel elements are polynomials of the form $p(x)=a_0$ is a constant. But by definition this means that the kernel is polynomials of degree $0$, i.e. $F$.

To see that $D$ is surjective, we just note that we can use the formal integral to produce a polynomial $P(x)$ such that $DP(x)=p(x)$. Namely

$$P(x)={1\over N+1}a_Nx^{N+1}+{1\over N}a_{N-1}x^{N}+\ldots+{1\over 2}a_1x^2+a_0x+C$$

for any $C\in F$.

Comment: a question here. For example what is $\frac{1}{2}a_1$? Is it defined?

Comment: Yes-- $2 = 1+1$ is in the field by closure. Since we are in characteristic $0$, we see $2\ne 0$ hence there is $2^{-1}\in F$ such that $2\cdot 2^{-1}=1$. By multiplicative closure $2^{-1}\cdot a_1\in F$

Comment: A bit confused. The 1 you mean is integer or identity?

Comment: My thought is i write the identity of $F$ as $e$ to avoid confusion. So as you said, $2e\in F$ and $2e\neq 0$ hence there exists $z$ such that $(2e)z=e$. Then consider $za_1x^2$. After differentiation, it becomes $2za_1x=2eza_1x=ea_1x=a_1x$.

Comment: You should absolutely not do that, a field has two different types of identity and has standard notation for each of them.